# Logging Subview Not Returning Correct Subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

At certain points in my application, I am adding a `UIView` to the keyWindow, and at other points I need to retrieve it in order to manipulate it.

I add the view like such:

```
self.minimizedView = [[UIViewCustomSubclass alloc] initWithFrame:viewFrame];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:self.minimizedView];
```

Later, in another class, I am attempting to iterate through the subviews of the keyWindow, like this:

```
for (id subview in [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.subviews) {
    NSLog(@"VIEW: %@ CLASS %@", [subview description], [subview class]);
}
```

I am using *id* here because I want to be typesafe in accessing only the right subview, because I need to move it's frame and I want to be sure I'm only moving the correct one... further to that point, I've subclassed `UIView` and created the view that I am adding to the keyWindow to be of that type...

Inside the above for loop, I am attempting to ask for isMemberOfClass:

```
if ([subview isMemberOfClass:[UIViewCustomSubclass class]]) {
    NSLog(@"The Subview %@ of Class %@ Should Be The One We Are Looking For", [subview description], [subview class]);
    // assign subview to iVar etc
}
```

But this never executes - the subview always logs it's class type to be of `UIView` (the superclass) but never of the subclass... I've set a breakpoint and inspected the View properties right at the point where I add it to the keyWindow, and it seems to be of the correct subclass type there...

Can anyone spot something that I'm doing wrong?

**-- EDIT --**

OOPS. I just found one edge case / place in my code where I am allocating the view still as a UIView and not as the subclass - this fixed the problem.

Comment: Could you add the code where you add your custom view to the window?

Comment: You're not checking the subviews of the subviews.  (And you should be using the data type `UIView *` for your `subview` variable, to use the closest known superclass.)

Comment: @HotLicks I don't want to check the subviews of my subviews... do I? (why?) to be clear, I **AM** getting the right view, it's just returning the wrong type...

Comment: @HotLicks Also, I was using UIView instead of id earlier, but because I **AM** getting the correct view but it is returning as a UIView instead of the subclass, I thought to not explicitly cast it...

Comment: The `class` method on NSObject always returns the actual class of the object instance -- it has nothing to do with the declared class of the pointer.

Comment: @HotLicks i see that now, and was confused that it 'wasn't' ... but yes, it was my fault for not catching an edge case where it wasn't properly allocated as the subclass, so was questioning myself...

Comment: Usually when you're sure you've found a bug in the compiler or iOS you've just made an excuse to stop looking for the bug in your own code.